# Chaining Routers with ONT modem/router

Tags: home-networking

I have the following the routers:

1. ONT modem/router that also has WiFi but limited features
2. Wireless router with long range antenna but no extender mode
3. Wireless router with extender mode but no external antenna

All will be connected by ethernt cables. I'd like #2 to be my main router (and DHCP server), to be placed in the middle of the house, while #3 is placed in the basement. However, due to the limited placement possibilities, I want to connect a PC to #1. Can this PC be within the network of #2? Also, can I switch roles between #2 and #3?

In short, will this topology work?
internet > ont-#1-lan > lan-#2-lan > lan-#3

Comment: What do you mean by "extender mode" here?

Comment: I mean that the router can function as a simple switch.

Answer (score 0):

Usually a SOHO(Small Office/Home Office) wifi router have 5 ethernet ports + Wifi

About ethernet/wifi ports :

- 1 is for the uplink (  internet side ) i will later reference as **UP_eth**
- 4 are use for internal local network.  i will later reference as **LO_eth_X**
- wifi is  often a extension of local network

You can build this topology

```
                                                      /--------\
                                               UP_eth:| WIFI 1 |:LO_eth_2 <=> #LOCAL_DEV#
                    /----------\                      | ROUTER |:LO_eth_3 <=> #LOCAL_DEV#
                    |          |:LO_eth1 <=> LO_eth_1:|        |:LO_eth_4 <=> #LOCAL_DEV#
                    | M A I N  |                      \--------/
                    |          |
INTERNET <=> UP_eth:| ROUTER   |:LO_eth2 <=> #LOCAL_DEV#
                    |          |:LO_eth3 <=> #LOCAL_DEV#
                    |          |                      /--------\
                    |          |:LO_eth4 <=> LO_eth_1:| WIFI 2 |:LO_eth_2 <=> #LOCAL_DEV#
                    \----------/                      | ROUTER |:LO_eth_3 <=> #LOCAL_DEV#
                                               UP_eth:|        |:LO_eth_4 <=> #LOCAL_DEV#
                                                      \--------/
```

Or you can build this topology

```
                       /----------\
                       | M A I N  |:LO_eth1 <=> #LOCAL_DEV#                 /--------\                                      /--------\
INTERNET   <=>  UP_eth:| ROUTER   |:LO_eth2 <=> #LOCAL_DEV#          UP_eth:| WIFI 1 |:LO_eth_2 <=> #LOCAL_DEV#      UP_eth:| WIFI 2 |:LO_eth_2 <=> #LOCAL_DEV#
                       |          |:LO_eth3 <=> #LOCAL_DEV#                 | ROUTER |:LO_eth_3 <=> #LOCAL_DEV#             | ROUTER |:LO_eth_3 <=> #LOCAL_DEV#
                       |          |:LO_eth4 <================> <=> LO_eth_1:|        |:LO_eth_4 <================> LO_eth_1:|        |:LO_eth_4 <=> #LOCAL_DEV#
                       \----------/                                         \--------/                                      \--------/
```

For BOTH toplogu , you must :

- turn OFF DHCP service on 2 routers in this case  , because you must have only 1 DHCP server by local network
- be sure that yours channel does overlap 
    see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels
- maximize usage of local ethernet ports ( wired will **ALMOST** be better that wifi ) .
   you can directly connect 8 devices ( 2  + 3 + 3 )

You can :

- Broadcast the same SSID with the same password on every WIFI
- reuse ... only in some cases the **UP_eth** port ... depends of the wifi router .
  Using the port **UP_eth** other than a uplink to INTERNET is tricky , because that usally add NAT translation .
  Some routers allow to convert the UP_eth as a regular , local PORT .